# take phone input from user in specific format

Tags: reactjs

```
9493468140  
(949)346-8140
949-346-8140      
19493468140  
+1 (949) 346-8140  
1-701-455-8962
```

this is my code i am using antd  form in react js

```
<Form.Item 
    name='Phone Number'
    rules=
    {
      [
     // pattern 
      { validator: validatePassword},
      { required: true,}
     ]
    }
    
     >
      <Input
              title='Phone Number'
              placeholder='+1(310)289-3126'
              showDot={false}
              
      />
    </Form.Item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this package: [React-Number-Format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-number-format)
install it via `npm` to your react project.

also you can use custom input with this package.